# Wordpress upload size increase

Tags: php, wordpress

I've tried to increase my upload size for wordpress in many ways. I tried doing it through my functions.php , through a php.ini file, through htaccess. No luck. When i try to upload a media file it says "Max upload size 1 MB". Latest i've tried was php.ini. I added this file to the wp-admin folder via FTP. It looks like follow:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
```

I even tried a plugin. And it stays at 1 MB. (this plugin worked on a previous website ). Now I feel like i've tried everything ive come to seek for help from the experts.

*** Important to know. Im using a multisite network.

Comment: you need to change in cpanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to you cpanel - MultiPHP Ini Editor. Select your website directory (refer screenshot)[image]

Then change shown parameters as per you requirement

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a plugin to increase max upload size.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/upload-max-file-size/
This is the plugin. I have used it many times and got the success.

After using this plugin, my media upload size became 250MB.

Thanks to this plugin.
Easy to use.

[image]